# Excel table fill column doesn't work

Tags: excel, fill

I'm having a very small but annoying issue. I can't seem to fill my column with the same value by double clicking the bottom-right corner.

This is what I click:

[image]

And it just changes the cell content into the content of the cell above it (so 'Weighting STP'). There is another value in the column which I have filtered because this one shouldn't be changed. I just want all empty cells to fill with the value 100%.

Why doesn't it do that? TIA!

Cheers

Comment: I noticed you decided not to include the row numbers from the right-most portion of the worksheet screen. Your column is filtered. Try it without the filter.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thanks for responding.

I can't do it unfiltered because it also has values in it then that can't change.
So it's thousands of rows where these values follow each other:
90%
blank
blank
90%
blank etc ....
So I just need the blank spaces to change into 100% automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fill down when cells are filtered. Instead, while it is still filtered, select all the visible cells using the mouse, and use Ctrl + Enter to add the 100% to all of them at once.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. Thanks but that are 10000s of cells to click?

Comment: Click the top one, then use Ctrl + Shift + Down Arrow. Or click the top one, then use the scrollbar at the right of the screen to scroll all the way to the bottom, then hold Shift and click the bottom one.

Comment: Do the above while your filter is still in place. I.e. just like you show in your image.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of trying different things and watching YouTube videos that supposedly fix this problem, I finally found that when using Excel `DataTable` objects, merged cells or filtered headers in the `datatable` give unexpected behavior.

You cannot auto-number a sequence of cells (down or across) based on a selected pattern of cells by double-clicking on the fill handle when ANY cells ARE MERGED or SORTED in that row or column.

Dragging the fill handle just copied formulas down, or if there are numbers in the cells, it will only copy the first cell value down or across.

You must unmerge and unsort all cells in that row or column.

Double-clicking the fill handle works (to copy down the sequence) after that.